# How to get AWStats Error Notification via email?

Tags: email, notifications, statistics, report, awstats

I'm trying to find a way for an *email notification* in awstats.

The idea is that whenever there's an error (missing log files, statistics couldn't be generated) an email with an error message should be send to a specific email address.

I already found the config-Attribute "ErrorMessages" but as far as i get it its just for displaying an error.

Is there an attribute like "ErrorMessages" for activating mail notifications or do i have to implement it myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cron job to run awstats update proccess. 
And it'll sent update process result via email to you.
Example:
* * * * * /usr/local/awstats/update.sh | mail abc@xzy.com

Comment: Thx Dieu, I think this could work. Haven't implemented it yet though.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to trap Errors while my code is executed. It's not an awstats feature, more a generic way:

Inside my script:

```
#Error Handling
set -e
function sendErrorNotification(){
        echo "Awstats: An error occured during processing server logs." | mail  -s "AWSTATS ERROR" "...@..."
    }
trap sendErrorNotification EXIT    

....code goes here...

set +e
trap - EXIT
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?